# gcc find installed libraries

Tags: c, gcc, dll

Is there a way to list all the installed libraries and/or query if a specific library is installed with gcc? I want to know if glut is available on my system (without browsing all the library path).

I am using mingw w/ gcc 4.5.2 under windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to check will generally be platform and compiler dependent. Getting it 100% right is hard.

You can use a build system like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) for generating your actual build system (confused yet `;-)`?)

I found [a small tutorial](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/tips/cmake.php) which explains how to find glut for you. Essentially, all you need is

```
find_package(GLUT)
```

in your `CMakeLists.txt`. To get to know cmake, I suggest you read/follow [their tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks, I know CMake can do that and probably you are right, what I wanted to do is if there is a shell command that locates installed libraries. I guess that the best way is to grep in library path then but thanks a lot any way.

Comment: @TheHube sure, you can search for files in the library path, but that won't tell you GLUT is installed correctly `;-)`. The best way is to just try and compile/link some test program.

Comment: Will do it for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet is to try to compile and link a simple example.
Gcc will complain about any libraries it can't find.

You may also try to use a smart IDE ([CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)) and try to auto-complete your #include statement. That may as well list all your installed libs.